# Plotting a grid with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a self-specified grid using Matplotlib in Python.

I know of the `np.meshgrid` function and can use it to obtain the array of different points I want to connect, but am unsure of how to then plot the grid.

Code example:

```
x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
y = np.linspace(0,10,20) 
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

Now, how can I plot a grid of this `xv` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn a grid on/off with [`grid()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.grid), but it's only possible to have the grid lines on axis ticks, so if you want it hand-made, what about this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

xs = np.linspace(0, 100, 51)
ys = np.linspace(0, 10, 21)
ax = plt.gca()
# grid "shades" (boxes)
w, h = xs[1] - xs[0], ys[1] - ys[0]
for i, x in enumerate(xs[:-1]):
    for j, y in enumerate(ys[:-1]):
        if i % 2 == j % 2: # racing flag style
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x, y), w, h, fill=True, color='#008610', alpha=.1))
# grid lines
for x in xs:
    plt.plot([x, x], [ys[0], ys[-1]], color='black', alpha=.33, linestyle=':')
for y in ys:
    plt.plot([xs[0], xs[-1]], [y, y], color='black', alpha=.33, linestyle=':')
plt.show()
```

[image: exapmple]

Comment: There is also `ax.vline` and `ax.hline`

Comment: Will it be possible to shade these blocks?

Comment: I added racing flag style block shading and made the lines dotted.

Answer (score 2):

It's much faster by using `LineCollection`:

```
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
y = np.linspace(0,10,20) 

pl.figure(figsize=(12, 7))

hlines = np.column_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(x[0], y, x[-1], y))
vlines = np.column_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(x, y[0], x, y[-1]))
lines = np.concatenate([hlines, vlines]).reshape(-1, 2, 2)
line_collection = LineCollection(lines, color="red", linewidths=1)
ax = pl.gca()
ax.add_collection(line_collection)
ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
ax.set_ylim(y[0], y[-1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  I wouldn't say the coding is faster or easier than the accepted answer though? Or do you mean the computational time?