# How do I plot a regular grid in matplotlib as a background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a grid onto the background of 2D plot line, similar as it is for ECG presentations, i.e. at specific points in regular interval dots are shown, e.g. as in this image

[image: Example for regular grid]

In this example there are precisely 4 dots spaced between to major dots. Want I don't want is sth as this [Plotting a grid with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429031/plotting-a-grid-with-matplotlib), i.e. just dotted grid lines

What I did so far (coming from ancient matlab knowledge) is this:

```
 xg = np.linspace(iStart/fs, iEnd/fs, len(y))
 yrange = ax.get_ylim()
 yg = np.linspace(yrange[0], yrange[1], 4)
 xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xg, yg)
 gridpoints, = plt.plot(xx.reshape(1,-1),yy.reshape(1,-1),linewidth=0.3,color='0.75',marker=".",markersize=10)
```

But it gets me this:
[image]

What am I not getting right?

Comment: I don't think you need to go that far. Can you try just using `plt.grid()`?

Comment: Sorry, I want a precisely defined grid pattern, which grid doesn't  give me

Comment: `plt.gird()` has several options, are you sure you cannot define it there?

Comment: @jpnadas I double checked the documentation, but not as far as I can see

Comment: have a look at major/minor grid lines... it might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. It was not an error in my thinking, but that my len(y) in the linspace of x was referencing the wrong vector, hencing producing a too fine grid, which looked like a line.

Answer (score 0):

As said by jpnadas you can use plt.grid()

here an example on how you can put and customize grid

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

img = plt.imread(imagename)
_, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1,nrows=1)
ax.imshow(img)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(16))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(16))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(32))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(32))

# Don't allow the axis to be on top of your data
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
# Turn on the minor TICKS, which are required for the minor GRID
ax.minorticks_on()
# Customize the major grid
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='4', color='yellow')
# Customize the minor grid
ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='2', color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I must clarify: What i want is a defined interval of the dots. I want to have exactly four minor dots between major dots. I will add that info to the explanation of the original post.

Comment: you can use linestyle=(0, (1, 4)), and linestyle=(0, (1, 2)), in the two ax.grid(). But I think that it doesn't solve because I'm not able to "align" dots